# Output full xml in Perl (XML::Xpath)

Tags: xml, perl

Some Perl code that I'm looking at is returning xml data from a method call. How do I view this xml data?

**Code:**

```
print "$xml";
```

**What I get:**

```
XML::XPath=HASH(0xa408dbc)
```

**What I want:**
Actual xml contents, i.e:

```
<sometag>
  <sometag2/>
</sometag>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you want one of

```
print $xml->find('/')->string_value;
print $xml->findnodes_as_string('/');
```

That is, find the root ('`/`') node of your XPath object, and print it out as a string.